# What is relationship between Wirtinger differential operator and multivariable chain rule?

Tags: complex-analysis, multivariable-calculus, harmonic-functions

What is relationship between [Wirtinger differential operator](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Cauchy-RiemannEquations.html)(equation 5) and [multivarible chain rule](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Cauchy-RiemannEquations.html)(equation 4)?
for other Wirtinger related questions look [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/314863/what-is-the-intuition-behind-the-wirtinger-derivatives).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\Omega$ be an open set in $\mathbf{C}$ (which identify with $\mathbf{R}^2$) and $f\in C^1(\Omega)$; as $2dx=dz+d\bar{z}$ and $2idy=dz-d\bar{z}$ we have
$$df=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}dx+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}dy=\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}dz+\frac{\partial f}{\partial\bar{z}}d\bar{z},$$
defining as usual
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}:=\frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}+\frac{1}{2i}\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}, \ \ \ \mathrm{and} \ \ \ \frac{\partial f}{\partial \bar{z}}:=\frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}-\frac{1}{2i}\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}.$$
Equation (4) is merely *formal* ($f$ is considered as a function of $z$ and $\bar{z}$, which are treated as independent variables even though they are conjugate); the notation is very suggestive, however if $f$ is holomorphic (so that $\partial f/\partial\bar{z}=0$) we have in fact $df/dz=\partial f/\partial z$ (where the left hand side is the *complex derivative*, see for instance Hörmander's An introduction to complex analysis in several variables.

Comment: I think the wirtinger derivatives are mixed up. the complex conjugate needs to be the one with the + in the middle, as stated here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wirtinger_derivatives .