# Complex Analysis based on Harmonic Function and Partial Derivatives

Tags: complex-analysis, partial-derivative, harmonic-functions, analytic-functions

Let u(x, y) be a harmonic function
Show that u(x, y) satisfy the differential equation (∂²u)/∂z∂z* = 0

**Where z is any complex number and z* is it's conjugate**

> My process is
> Since u(x, y) is harmonic, thus
> Uxx + Uyy = 0

Now I am just stuck at
Expanding (∂u)/∂z∂z*

Please help

Comment: Hint: you may want to look here:https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2126598/how-does-the-derivative-with-respect-to-the-complex-conjugate-even-make-sense

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 0):

First observe
$x=\frac{z+\bar{z}}{2}$ & $y=\frac{z-\bar{z}}{2i}$

Now,
$\frac{\partial u}{\partial \bar{z}}$ =$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\times\frac{\partial x}{\partial \bar{z}}$ +$\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\times\frac{\partial y}{\partial \bar{z}}$

Similarly use chain rule in next stage to get answer 0