# $\text {Prove that f is analytic if and only if}$ $\frac{\partial f}{\partial \overline{Z}}=0$

Tags: complex-analysis

$\text {Prove that f is analytic if and only if}$  $\frac{\partial f}{\partial \overline{Z}}=0$

MY attempt:

suppose f is analytic $f(z)=u+iv \text{ then } u_x=v_y \text{ and } u_y=-v_x\\
\text{also } x=\frac{z+\overline{z}}{2},y=\frac{z-\overline{z}}{2i}\\
\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial \overline{z}}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial \overline{z}}=0$

but to prove converse part of this statement

Comment: One has $\frac{\partial f}{\partial \bar z}(z_0) =\frac 12\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial  x}(z_0)  +i\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(z_0) \right) $, and the vanishing of this at $z_0$ amounts to the Cauchy--Riemann equations.

Comment: See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/314863/what-is-the-intuition-behind-the-wirtinger-derivatives), too.