# Intuition for $f'(z)= \partial_x f =\frac{1}{i} \partial_y f$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, intuition

What's the intuition behind $f'(z)= \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ and $f'(z)= \frac{1}{i} \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$, where $f : \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ is assumed to be analytic?

I know the algebraic proof of this, but I am not sure what these equations really mean. If anyone could explain why these equations should be true, I would be grateful!

**EDIT :** Having thought about it a bit more I think these equations are not so dramatic. For an analytic function the derivative must agree with the directional derivatives ( this can probably be said better ) and this is, I suppose, just what these equations are saying.

Comment: No, I seek understanding of the seperate equations, not of the proof of these equations or some relationship between them.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense.

Comment: I am a bit confused, why do you write a partial derivative w.r.t $z$? $f$ only has one variable..

Comment: @Yourong Zang Follows more or less from this post https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/314863/what-is-the-intuition-behind-the-wirtinger-derivatives?fbclid=IwAR2j-g7gJZMqm5yACzhDAiOpeSuF7oydhbfdIFPD2ZVSv6U1f8eXomc1izQ

Comment: @ Strichcoder Sorry will edit it. No reason for this to be partial!

Comment: @Strichcoder if $f$ is analytic, i.e., complex-differentiable, $\frac{df}{dz}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}$. So it's ok to write a partial derivative.

Comment: @Strichcoder yes, but best not cause confusion!

Comment: Made an edit to my original post!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f'(z) = \lim_{h \to 0} {f(z+h)-f(z) \over h }$, where $h \in \mathbb{C}$.

Hence $f'(z) = \lim_{t \to 0, t \in \mathbb{R}} {f(z+t)-f(z) \over t } = \partial_x f(z)$
and
$f'(z) = \lim_{t \to 0, t \in \mathbb{R}} {f(z+it)-f(z) \over it } = {1 \over i}\partial_y f(z)$.

Comment: So it is essentially what I said in my edit?

Comment: Well, less directional derivative and more that the limit is independent of how $h->0$.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks!

Comment: Btw are these equations useful in practice(i.e. are they useful for computing derivatives etc.)?

Comment: Sometimes. ${}{}{}{}$